# Migrate an existing java (libGDX) project and git repository from eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm a Java and Web developer.

After using eclipse for 5 years, I decided to at least try to migrate my currently active projects to the JetBrains IDE.

Mainly because of the new features for Android Studio that have been announced at Google IO 15 and I feel that it might be better for me to familiarize myself with it in general. Just in case the support for ADT in eclipse is dropped by Google at some point.
I also noticed that the Laravel (PHP framework) integration is pretty good for IntelliJ, which would come in handy for some of my planned Web projects.

The Java project I'd like to migrate is more specific a libGDX game which has a git repo.

So my question(s) are:

- Is it possible to convert the project from an eclipse project to an IntelliJ project, without loosing the git repository?
- Does anyone have got experience with this?
- Does anyone know if there will be issues with files generated by the libGDX setup tool?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I know that there is an import option for eclipse projects to convert them to the IDEA structure, but I'm not sure if that will also handle git.

Comment: You don't even need the eclipse importer. Just import the project "from existing source" and IntelliJ will figure it out. When the project is there, it'll tell you that there is an "unregistered Source Control root", with an option to add it. And that'll be it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could just try it, IntelliJ won't delete you anything. You could even use both IDEs on the same sources.

If you create a project or module from a directory which is versioned (e.g. contains .git), then IntelliJ will automatically pick it up, so you can use it.